Transparent window on android api level 28 goes black
I just can't find an answer for this.
I have some activities, some of them will be on top of others by starting a new Activity. Following theme them is applied to the topmost ones so they appear transparent, so I can see the parent activity.
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.5</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>

This is a sample of the top activity
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Now, this does work fine on API level 31. A new activity aligns to the end, with 150 width units, so the rest of the screen is semi-transparent. Thats fine.
Problem is when I switch to an older API level such as 26 or 28, and screen goes black instead of transparent.
I have tried everything in my hands, but I had no luck. Tried a lot of different themes, none of them working on API level 28 and lower. The only one working is using @android:style/Theme.Translucent, but it does show me the title bar which I dont need, also I need to use AppCompat to use SwitchCompat
Any clue what else to try?
